# Excel Interop - Add Worksheet and change name via return value

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

i'm trying to change the name of a Worksheet created via the `Add` method with the usage of it's return value. This is suggested by several anwsers on stackoverflow. But it doesn't work and gives an COMException with the error code `0x800401A8`. The other two methods work fine. Can someone give me a hint why the first method isn't working?

The Code:

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileInfo.FullName);

// Creates a new worksheet, chart, or macro sheet. The new worksheet becomes the active sheet.
var sheet = wb.Sheets.Add(Before: Type.Missing, After: wb.Sheets[wb.Sheets.Count], Count: 1, Type: XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);

try
{
    ((Worksheet)sheet).Name = "ASDF";
    
    
} catch(COMException e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine($"Fail 1 - 0x{e.ErrorCode:X}");
}
try
{
    ((Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet).Name = "ASDF";
} catch(COMException e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine($"Fail 2 - 0x{e.ErrorCode:X}");
}

try
{
    ((Worksheet) wb.Sheets[wb.Sheets.Count]).Name = "ASDF";
} catch (COMException e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine($"Fail 3 - 0x{e.ErrorCode:X}");
}
```

The Trace Output:

```
Fail 1 - 0x800401A8
```

The exception in detail:

```
threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    ErrorCode: -2147221080
    HResult: -2147221080
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "0x800401A8"
    Source: "Testfall-Manager"
    StackTrace: "   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.set_Name(String RHS)"
    TargetSite: {Void set_Name(System.String)}
```

Comment: Your code works for me, using Interop.Excel v15.0 from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/), running against Excel 2019 v14131.

Comment: Did you mind the try/catch-Blocks? Also only the first method doesn't work for me

Comment: Yes, all 3 of them succeeded (I tried them independently from each other). If you're not married to using Interop, there are other libraries that will manipulate Excel files - a lot better, faster, and more efficient than Interop. (e.g. EPPlus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the excel file itself. Above methods work fine with an empty excel file (xlsx)